# Cannot resolve symbol 'LastModifiedFileComparator'

Tags: java, android

I am writing a project that makes use of LastModifiedFileComparator and I tried import this

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
```

but it shows the error.

```
cannot resolve symbol 'LastModifiedFileComparator'
```

I have put in these dependencies

```
// In top-level gradle file
repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
}

// In app gradle file
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
implementation files('commons-io-2.6.jar')
```

Comment: Given the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/LastModifiedFileComparator.html) I suspect you want commons-io 1.4. (Although it looks like commons-io-2.6.jar should include it too...)

Answer (score 0):

This class is not present in the version 1.3.2

Upgrade the version to 1.4 or greater

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

Comment: I have updated the version to 1.4 and 2.6 respectively and the error is ```ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.4
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app``` and ```ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-io:2.6
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by downloading `commons-io-1.4.jar` with my browser and then copy and paste it in the android project lib